# How make ViewPager like Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'd like to make a ViewPager like Google Play or Facebook. For who don't know what I'm saying, the image below shows what I want to do.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have a look at RecyclerView

Comment: @chRyNaN I don't found any tutorial to do it. Can you show me how I can found a tutorial to make that?

Comment: You can find a tutorial by using a search engine. You are looking to implement a horizontal RecylcerView not a ViewPager. This site is not made for people to do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jaydeep, this is the way

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a horizontal LinearLayout inside a ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

use recycler view and set LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL in LayoutManager

linearLayoutManagerHorizontal =new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

Here is a link of a sample tutorial : http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/linearlayoutmanager-and.html

Comment: Thanks @Jaydeep I was using ViewPager, but you're right, I'll use RecyclerView. When I swipe, how can I make centralize the layout like a ViewPager?